# tableview: detect changes in the filtered list

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table containing multiple columns and rows where new rows can be added, existing rows can be edited and removed. There is an action column where corresponding row value will be true if any change occurs. And my table is filtered(sorted). Now I am trying to detect changes in my table like edited or added or removed. I tried to do it through `ListChangeListener` and here is my related code a glimpse of my table.

[image]

```
private ObservableList<ModelBrFloor> floordata =FXCollections.observableArrayList(floor ->
        new Observable[] {
           floor.FloorNameProperty(),
           floor.FloorCodeProperty(),
        floor.FloorNumberProperty()

        });
private ObservableList<ModelBrFloor> getInfo(ModelBrBuilding building) {


            floordata.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends ModelBrFloor> c) -> {
                   while (c.next()) {
                       if (c.wasAdded()) {
                           System.out.println("Added:");
                           c.getAddedSubList().forEach(System.out::println);
                           System.out.println();
                       }
                       if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                           System.out.println("Removed:");
                           c.getRemoved().forEach(System.out::println);
                           System.out.println();
                       }
                       if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                            //have to make column value true here
                           System.out.println("Updated:");
                           floordata.subList(c.getFrom(), c.getTo()).forEach(System.out::println);
                           System.out.println();
                       }
                   }
                });
            floordata = FXCollections.observableArrayList(implementation.getFloor(building));

            FilteredList<ModelBrFloor> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(floordata,p->true);
            txtFloorName.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
                filteredData.setPredicate(BCode->{
                if(newValue== null||newValue.isEmpty())
                {   return true;

                }
                String lowerCasefilter=newValue.toLowerCase();
                if(BCode.getFloorName()!=null)
                 if (BCode.getFloorName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter)){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                });

            });
            txtFloorShort.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
            filteredData.setPredicate(BCode->{
                if(newValue== null || newValue.isEmpty())
                    return true;
                String lowerCasefilter= newValue.toLowerCase();
                if(BCode.getFloorCode()!=null)
                if(BCode.getFloorCode().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasefilter))
                    return true;
                return false;
            });

            });
            txtFloorNo.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
                filteredData.setPredicate(BCode->{
                    if(newValue== null || newValue.isEmpty())
                        return true;
                    int val=BCode.getFloorNumber();
                    if(String.valueOf(val).equals(newValue))
                        return true;
                    return false;
                    });
            });

            SortedList sortedData = new SortedList(filteredData);

            sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableBuilding.comparatorProperty());
            return sortedData;

        }
```

My problem is this code compiling well but printing nothing (also not sure how to get edited row to turn false into true). Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: You're adding the listener to the list just before replacing it with a new list... I guess you don't have access to the old list anywhere to modify it....

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @fabian how can I do that??